# How to resize this jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking at the jQuery mobile panels demo - In particular there is an icon that opens the sliding side menu:

The markup for this element looks like this:

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/panel-fixed/

```
<a href="#nav-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-link ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-notext ui-shadow ui-corner-all" data-role="button" role="button">Menu</a>
```

I'm trying to resize and center this element. I tried adding width and height styles but that just makes it look bad. Then I tried changing the font-size thinking it was a font glyph and that didn't work either. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a background-image (encoded svg). You can adjust the size like this (but you'll also need to adjust the size of the containing elment for it to make sense/not get cut off)

```
.ui-icon-bars:after
    background-size: 200%;
}
```